# Are custom elements not allowed to manipulate their own child nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

This, of course, works:

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
   super()
    
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).
      appendChild(document.createTextNode('asdf'))
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)

document.body.appendChild(
  document.createElement('my-element'))
```

But is defining shadow DOM necessary here? Let’s see what happens without it:

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.appendChild(document.createTextNode('asdf'))
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)

document.body.appendChild(
  document.createElement('my-element'))
```

Suddenly this throws. And no, it’s not the constructor that throws - it’s `document.createElement`.

Oddly, forgoing `document.createElement` and instead using the constructor directly seems to work beautifully:

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.appendChild(document.createTextNode('asdf'))
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)

document.body.appendChild(new MyElement())
```

I am confused here. Are custom elements forbidden to manipulate their own child nodes? And not only child nodes, doing something as simple as `this.style.color = 'red'` inside a custom element produces same results. But if they’re forbidden to do this, then why does calling the constructor directly work as expected? What is going on here?

Do I have to use shadow DOM or am I allowed to forgo it?